# Docker container with application - database in container or not

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to talk about using docker container as application.

I would like to create application which will use database (and maybe another stuff). 
I'm confusing how to do it properly.

I can do it in two ways:

1. Use docker-compose to create containers like database and my
   application separately
2. Install database on my application container
   and use as single container

**Which approach is better ?**

- When I choose 1st - someone may doesn't have docker-compose and have to setup application in docker-compose file.
- When I choose 2nd - I can create single-container, standalone application.

Comment: Is this for a local/test environment, or is this for "production"?

Comment: For production. I would like to put this container to docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

The single container approach is not recommended. Check the docker documentation to how to [start mulitple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/).

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
>   using one service per container. That service may fork into multiple
>   processes (for example, Apache web server starts multiple worker
>   processes). It’s ok to have multiple processes, but to get the most
>   benefit out of Docker, avoid one container being responsible for
>   multiple aspects of your overall application.

As you can see, starting multiple services is doable but is not recommended and introduces a lot of complexity.

> When I choose 1st - someone may doesn't have docker-compose and have
>   to setup application in docker-compose file.

Docker compose is just a helper. Everything that can be done with compose can be done with a sequence of docker commands.